# Giving another class to child elements: wp_nav_menu (walker)

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, themes

I have a problem on giving to child items only the class I want.

Anyone can give me some hints or any little help on what I have to write on my functions.php ?
Here's my code:
sidebar.php:

```
<?php
    wp_nav_menu(array(
        'container' => 'div',
        'container_class' => 'menu',
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s',
        'walker' => new ik_walker
    ));
?>
```

functions.php:

```
class ik_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu{

    var $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );
    var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

    function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth=0, $args, &$output )
    {
        $id_field = $this->db_fields['id'];
        if ( is_object( $args[0] ) ) {
            $args[0]->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[$element->$id_field] );
        }
        return parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
    }    

    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $output .= "<i class=\"dropdown icon\"></i>\n";
        $output .= "<div class=\"menu\">\n";
    }

    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "</div></div>\n";
    }

    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        $value = '';
        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes = in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) ? array( 'current-menu-item' ) : array();
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = strlen( trim( $class_names ) ) > 0 ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', '', $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';
        $item_output = $args->before;


        if ($args->has_children){

            $item_output .= "<div class=\"ui simple dropdown item\">\n";
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        }

        else {
            $item_output .= "<div class=\"ui simple dropdown item\">\n";
            $item_output .= "<a". $attributes . $id . $value . $class_names . ">\n";
            $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= "\n</a><i class=\"dropdown icon\"></i></div>\n";
        }

        $item_output .= $args->after;
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }




}
```

I want the output to be like this :

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    CATEGORY WITH SUB-CATEGORIES
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="item" ><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a></div>
      <div class="item" ><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a></div>
      <div class="item" ><a href="#">Sub Category 3</a></div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.ui .simple .dropdown .item -->

  <div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    CATEGORY WITHOUT SUB-CATEGORY
  </div>
</div> <!-- /.menu -->
```

at the moment, the menu is display like this (classes **ui simple dropdown item** are outputed, but I want them to be only : **item**, also without the `<i>` thing. )

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    CATEGORY WITH SUB-CATEGORIES
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="ui simple dropdown item"><a href="#">Sub Category 1</a><i class="dropdown icon"></i></div>
      <div class="ui simple dropdown item"><a href="#">Sub Category 2</a><i class="dropdown icon"></i></div>
      <div class="ui simple dropdown item"><a href="#">Sub Category 3</a><i class="dropdown icon"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.ui .simple .dropdown .item -->

  <div class="ui simple dropdown item">
    CATEGORY WITHOUT SUB-CATEGORY
  </div>
</div> <!-- /.menu -->
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's these lines that you should concentrate on, in the function `start_el()` -

```
$classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
$classes = in_array( 'current-menu-item', $classes ) ? array( 'current-menu-item' ) : array();
```

They're grabbing the default classes from `$item`, which obviously you don't want. If you want them all to have just the single call `item` (not bothering with `current-menu-item`), then replace with this -

```
$classes = array('item');
```

However, if you want to still include `current-menu-item` then replace it with this -

```
$classes = in_array('current-menu-item', $item->classes) ? array('current-menu-item') : array();
$classes[] = 'item';
```